# Adding and removing items from arrays, based on a condition in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm trying to make a dynamic "favorites" toggle-button.
When clicking the button, it should add the selected player to the users favorite-list. If the player is already favorited, it should remove it.

I've also tried to iterate through the favorites, to check if a player is already favorited. If true, it colors the favorite star gold.

A few problems here. My for loop for checking seems to be working properly as long as the array only contains one item. But as soon as I try adding more, the gold icon is only gold colored on the last player added to favorites. So the check only finds one favorite at a time, and I can add a player to favorites many times, as long as I vary the players I add.

If someone could point me in the right direction and help me understand why my loop isn't working correctly, that would be awesome!

http://codepen.io/utrolig/pen/LNgRwv

Javascript

```
angular.module('test', [])

  .controller('TestController', function($scope){
    $scope.players = [
      {
        uniqueid: "gem",
        name: "Ole Christian",
        cake: false,
      },{
        uniqueid: "utrolig",
        name: "Stian",
        cake: false,
      },{
        uniqueid: "drozo",
        name: "Adrian",
        cake: false,
      }
    ];

    $scope.user = {
      name: "Stian",
      username: "stiba",
      favorites: [{uniqueid: "drozo"}],
    }

    $scope.checkFavorite = function(id){
      fav = $scope.user.favorites;
      var exists;
      for (var i=0; i < fav.length; i++){
        if(fav[i].uniqueid == id){
          exists = true;
        } else {
          exists = false;
        } 
      }
      return exists;
    }

    $scope.toggleFavorite = function(id){
      fav = $scope.user.favorites;
      if(fav.length === 0){
        var newfav = {uniqueid: id};
        fav.push(newfav);
      } else {
         if($scope.checkFavorite(id) === true){
          for(var i = 0; i < fav.length; i++){
             if (fav[i].uniqueid === id) fav.splice(i, 1);
          }
        } else if ($scope.checkFavorite(id) === false) {
          var newfav = {uniqueid: id};
          fav.push(newfav)
        } else {
          console.log('Error!');
        } 
      }
    }

    $scope.isFavorited = function(){
      return true;
    };

  })
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="test">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="TestController">
    <h3>Players</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="player in players" class="player-cont">
      <div class="player">
        <div class="favorite" ng-click="toggleFavorite(player.uniqueid)" ng-class="{'active': checkFavorite(player.uniqueid)}">
          <i class="material-icons">star</i>
        </div>
        <i class="material-icons player-icon">person</i>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p ng-bind="player.uniqueid"></p>
        <p ng-bind="player.name"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h3>Favorites</h3>
    <div ng-repeat="favorite in user.favorites track by $index">
      <h5>{{favorite.uniqueid}}</h5>
    </div>
    <p class="user">
    {{user.favorites}}
    </p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "everything breaks". What is the expected behavior and what is the actual behavior?

Comment: Edited my post. If you check the codepen and click, the stars, I think it would be easier to understand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of errors in your code.

The first is `checkFavorite`, if you examine the code you'll see that only the *last* item is actually compared to `id`, since the `exists` flag is updated for each item. You need to "short circuit" the loop and return true as soon as you find a value.

btw, `is*` is a common name convention for checking boolean values.

```
$scope.isFavorite = function(id){
  var fav = $scope.user.favorites;
  for (var i=0; i < fav.length; i++){
    if(fav[i].uniqueid == id){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Your toggle is also very verbose, if you "reduce" the code you end up with something like this

```
$scope.toggleFavorite = function(id){
  var fav = $scope.user.favorites;
  // no previous items, remove, OK
  if(fav.length === 0) {
    var newfav = {uniqueid: id};
    fav.push(newfav);
    return;
  }

  // if already a favorite, uncheck/remove
  if($scope.isFavorite(id)) {
    for(var i = 0; i < fav.length; i++){
       if (fav[i].uniqueid === id) fav.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  // otherwise add the item
  // remember, isFavorite returns true of false, there is no third state
  else { // if ($scope.isFavorite(id) === false) {
    var newfav = {uniqueid: id};
    fav.push(newfav)
  }
}
```

This can be edited further, since the isFavorite function will return false if the list is empty, i.e. no need for the first `if`

```
$scope.toggleFavorite = function(id){
  var fav = $scope.user.favorites;
  // if already a favorite, uncheck/remove
  if($scope.isFavorite(id)) {
    for(var i = 0; i < fav.length; i++){
       if (fav[i].uniqueid === id) {
         fav.splice(i, 1);
         // unless the item exists more than once, break the loop
         break;
       }
    }
  }
  // otherwise add the item
  else {
    var newfav = {uniqueid: id};
    fav.push(newfav)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems I need to go back to basics before I continue with my angular-skills..

Comment: @StianBakken; np. Remember that you can optimize it further since in the current case you are looping through the list of favorites twice.